# Anyone can recommend some scroll jquery plugin which can be used in one page web design?

Tags: jquery

Just as i mention above, i need develope one page website , need some good jquery plugin, thanks!

Comment: That depends on what type of things you want to show on your page. It will be great if you can tell what exactly needs to be done.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this plugin: [jQuery one page nav](http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav), here is a demo for what exactly you need:  http://www.gbin1.com/technology/jquerynews/20120421jquerypluginonpagenav/demo1.html

Or you can try some other plugin like [waypoint](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/):

Hope it can help！